# Why continuation executes asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, continuations

The code sample below

```csharp
public static void Test()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> inner = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> outer = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    TaskScheduler ctScheduler = new CurrentThreadTaskScheduler();

    outer.Task.ContinueWith(
        completedTask =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Continuation of the outer in the thread #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            inner.SetResult(true);
        },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default);

    Task t = Task.Run(
        async () =>
        {
            await inner.Task;
            Console.WriteLine("Awaiter continuation in the thread #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Setting the outer to completed in the thread #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    outer.SetResult(true);
}
```

produces the following output

> Setting the outer to completed in the thread #1
> Continuation of the outer in the thread #4
> Awaiter continuation in the thread #4

As expected, the continuation after `await inner.Task` was executed synchronously on the thread which completed the task, namely the thread #4.
When I'm trying to run all the continuations synchronously on the same current thread

```csharp
outer.Task.ContinueWith(
completedTask =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Continuation of the outer in the thread #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    inner.SetResult(true);
},
CancellationToken.None,
TaskContinuationOptions.None,
ctScheduler);
```

using a simple custom task scheduler, implemented as follows

```csharp
public sealed class CurrentThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Task>();
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }
}
```

the 'awaiter' continuation runs asynchronously, as seen in the output down here

> Setting the outer to completed in the thread #1
> Continuation of the outer in the thread #1
> Awaiter continuation in the thread #4

Why the continuation in question is running asynchronously and how should I implement the scheduler to guarantee the expected behaviour?

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: @PeterCsala: If the continuation had been executed synchronously, as expected, it would be 'Awaiter continuation in the thread #1'

Comment: What is the use case that requires this behaviour?